# How to attach jQuery tooltip to jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-tooltip

I have jQuery UI datepicker running with some highlighted dates with custom titles. What I want to do is to display these titles with jQuery UI tooltip. Simplified code (all days higlighted for simplicity):

```
jQuery('.seminars__calendar').datepicker({

     beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [true, 'highlight', 'The custom title'];
     },

});

jQuery('.seminars__calendar .highlight a').tooltip();
```

This doesnt work. I suppose that is because the calendar is created dynamically and tooltip is not attached to these dynamically created links. If I change the last line to `jQuery('.seminars__calendar').tooltip();` It works fine but tooltips are also shown on "next", "prev" links in calendar and I dont want that. I want tooltip on highlighted days only. Is it possible?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfjo5a0g/  (It is working at first but if you switch to the next month in datepicker it stops)

Comment: Please provide a sample fiddle, where we can working out in a solution

Comment: I have edited the post and added link to jsfiddle.

Comment: why not just `jQuery('.seminars__calendar').datepicker().tooltip();`

Comment: In your fiddle works fine...tooltip not showing on next and prev...

Comment: @RobertRozas it is showing on my browser its not showing `This custom title` its showing `Prev` in the style of the tooltip.

Comment: Name your web browser and version please.

Comment: @RobertRozas For OP not sure but it is doing it for me in the latest Chrome version

Comment: @Sebastien is working for me too in Chrome...it's better to wait for the OP to answer my question about his browser xD

Comment: @RobertRozas I think you misunderstood what I was saying, for me in Chrome latest version, for `Prev` and `Next` a tooltip appear with the text `prev/next` what I think the OP want is to stop the tooltip from showing on the `Prev/Next` buttons.

Comment: @RobertRozas maybe you could check the difference between the OP fiddle and the one in my answer you'll see what I mean

Comment: Thank you guys. Solution with `jQuery('.seminars__calendar').datepicker().tooltip();` works BUT it is showing tooltip on next/prev links. I dont want that. See my original question. I dont think browser version is something important here since we are seeing the same results. Anyway Chrome 36.

Answer (score 1):

you could just use the JQuery tooltip's option `content` like this:

```
$('.seminars__calendar').datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return [true, 'highlight', 'The custom title'];
    },
});

$('.seminars__calendar .highlight a').tooltip({content:"this is a test"});
```

But it will overwrite your `The custome title`.

**--EDIT--**

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/oe5kjwga/

And doc here: http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content

Comment: Thank you but as you say this overrides the custom title. I want different for each date depending on some logic. I have simplified the code to fiddle.

Comment: Its very useful, thnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have solved this. It is needed to reattach .tooltip() after datepicker redraws itself after month/year change. I have tried to add it to onChangeMonthYear datepicker event but no luck (callback is called before datepicker is redrawn).

This works for me (adding toolip everytime you enter calendar with a cursor):

```
$('.seminars__calendar').on('mouseenter', ".ui-datepicker-calendar", function() {
            $(this).tooltip();
        });
```